# Laravel named route URL with parameter not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm trying to generate a url with parameter using laravel route helper,

```
route('frontend.admin.categories.edit', $catRequest->id)
```

but this is the generated url

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/categories/edit?1
```

I need a URL like this

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/categories/edit/1
```

And this is my route

```
 Route::get('admin/categories/edit/{id}', 'CategoryController@edit')
        ->name('admin.categories.edit');
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the parameter(s) you are replacing by passing an associative array instead of a variable.

Change,

```
route('frontend.admin.categories.edit', $catRequest->id)
```

To

```
route('frontend.admin.categories.edit', [
    'id' => $catRequest->id
]);
```

### Edit #1

You are calling the wrong route, you named your route as `admin.categories.edit` in the definition yet you are calling `frontend.admin.categories.edit` within the helper function which is not the originally defined route. So your code should be:

```
route('admin.categories.edit', [
    'id' => $catRequest->id
]);
```

**Reading Material**

[Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes)

Comment: No luck. Still the result http://localhost:8000/admin/categories/edit?id=4

Comment: @FortunaglobalDevelopment you are calling the wrong route, you defined it as `admin.categories.edit` yet you are calling `frontend.admin.categories.edit`. See **Edit #1**.

Comment: Do you have duplicate named routes?

Comment: No. This happend with another routes too. Is is the configurations issue. To my knowledge there is no need of configuring url generation in laravel

Comment: If you open CMD and go to your project DIR and then run `php artisan serve` , it should say that the application has been setup on localhost:port, go to that URL and try and load that URL. Does it show the URL how you want it to?

Comment: I'm already in the correct url. But the url is worng. Parameter shows as a get parameter

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array for your params :

```
route('frontend.admin.categories.edit', ['id' => $catRequest->id])
```

If not, all params will be used as $_GET params.

Comment: if there are more than one parameters in route  then we use array otherwise one parameter can be passed as second param

Answer (score 0):

Try to view your route list using `php artisan route:list`. If you found your route in list with correct Uri then see that you are not again specify that route with same Uri or same alias name in your route file.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have another route with the same name right after this one in the code that may be overwriting the above route params, i had the same problem and in my case this is what was happening, i had two routes definitions using the same name but with different http methods like the example below.
Ex:

```
Route::get('/route1/{param1}');
Route::post('/route1');
redirect()->route('/route1', ['test']); // output: /route1?test
```

When i've changed it to:

```
Route::post('/route1');
Route::get('/route1/{param1}');
redirect()->route('/route1', ['test']); // output: /route1/test
```

then i got the desired result.